# Discord.net Configuration Builder Error - Unsure how to fix

Tags: c#, .net, discord.net

```
            _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "bot_")
                .AddJsonFile("bot_info.json", optional: true)
                .Build();
```

I understand it is setting up some kind of configuration and adding something to my `bot_info.json` file but I don't understand what.

I am getting this error on line 2:
[image: Error on line 2]

I have tried asking in the DNET server for over a week now, no results. So I am turning here.

Entire file (and bot): https://github.com/DudeThatsErin/csharpbot/blob/master/Program.cs

I am trying to get my bot to come online using the information that is in the bot_info.json in such a way that the bot_info.json does not get uploaded to GitHub (open source) and so that the prefix is `bot_`

Comment: This isn't actully a DNet issue. Try installing the [UserSecrets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets/) package as well.

Comment: Didn't work @Anu6is. Installed and same error. I even tried rebooting Visual Studio and same error is appearing.

Comment: Actually looking at your [csproj](https://github.com/DudeThatsErin/csharpbot/blob/master/csharpbot.csproj) file, why are you installing version 7 of the packages when your project targets .Net6? You should downgrade the packages

Comment: Upgraded the .net to v 7.0 and that did not solve the issue.

I pushed all of my changes to GitHub. So it has the latest updates of every file.

Thanks for the help thus far @Anu6is!

Comment: Based on the current github, you don't have `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables` installed. You'd also need `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` for the `AddJsonFile`

Comment: Now on these lines:             if (Program.IsDebug())
                await _handler.RegisterCommandsToGuildAsync(_configuration.GetValue<ulong>("testGuild"), true);
            else
                await _handler.RegisterCommandsGloballyAsync(true);

I am getting `GetValue` is not part of _configuration. This is on my interactionhandler.cs file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251271/discussion-between-erin-and-anu6is).

Comment: @Rob that's not an image, that is copy and paste of code and `GetValue` is using backticks and formatted. @Anu6is have you been able to look at this yet?

Comment: Funny because, when I try to copy the "error on line 2", I can't because **it acts like an image**.

Comment: @Rob That error is solved. I have an error just before your comment that I am now stuck on.